# Updating an object with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to update the value of "**Designation**" but when I click on the first item, the form is automatically populated with the LAST value that was inserted and not with the one I clicked on, 
 for instance if I wanted to update the value of "**FM2**" I will get "**tst**"  in the form :

[image: Displaying the values]

[image: When I click to update "FM2" value]

This is the view code :

```
    @extends('dashboard.layout')

@section('title' , 'Manage Sockets')
@section('pageHeader', 'Sockets')

@section('content')

    <div class="card">

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="data-table-basic" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
                    <th data-column-id="sender">Designation</th>
                    <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Updated on</th>
                    <th data-column-id="operations" data-order="desc">Operations</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($sockets as $socket)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$socket->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$socket->designation}}</td>
                            <td>{{$socket->updated_at}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{action('SocketController@delete', ['id' =>$socket->id ])}}" class="btn bgm-cyan waves-effect"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i></a>
                                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modalDefault"  class="btn bgm-orange waves-effect"><i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i></a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalDefault" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Update A Socket</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {!! Form::model($socket,['route' =>['socketupdate',$socket->id],'method'=>'POST']) !!}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10" >
                            <!-- text input for designation -->
                            <div class="form-group fg-float">
                                <div class="fg-line">
                                    {!! Form::label('designation', 'designation:',['class' => 'fg-label']) !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('designation',null,['class' => 'form-control fg-input input-sm']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-sm-12" >
                            <button class="btn bgm-blue center-block" style="display: flex" type="submit" >Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn bgm-cyan btn-icon waves-effect waves-circle waves-float"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <button class="btn bgm-lightgreen btn-icon waves-effect waves-circle waves-float">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>
    </button>
    @include('forms.socket')

@endsection

@section('additional_scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').on('click', '#btn-color-targets > .btn', function(){
                var color = $(this).data('target-color');
                $('#modalColor').attr('data-modal-color', color);
            });
        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: are you populating the model with data from an ajax request based on the id of the item you are trying to edit?

Comment: no I'm populating the model with a basic form not using ajax, it's almost the same code from the form builder

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Actually I just noticed that it's always updating the last value, even if I select the first one, here's the code of the view :
http://pastebin.com/T9YGJ9GD

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @HimanshuRaval I did

Comment: @hadh look at my answer

Comment: @HimanshuRaval yes I saw your answer and can you explain some more? I don't understand what rep_id should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code either you have to set all models separately for each record which is not advisable 
or 
you can do something like change your bootstrap modal's content and the route parameter id dynamically on click via jquery otherwise it will only take last entered records id as u are setting it.
so
change

```
{!! Form::model($socket,['route' =>['socketupdate',$socket->id],'method'=>'POST']) !!}
```

to

```
 {!! Form::model($socket,['route' =>['socketupdate',rep_id],'method'=>'POST']) !!}
```

and replace rep_id on edit button click.

Comment: can you explain some more please?

Comment: hey look here you have set a static $socket->id so it will update only one record every time so you have to change that id dynamically.